# Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

DIRECTORY STRUCTURE IS

```
 ProjectNAame
   |   -----JavaResources
   |         :
   |         :-src/main/java
   |          -src/main/resources 
   |                 |
   |                  |Hibernate-SessionFactory.xml
   |                  |Spring-Security.xml
   |
   |
   |________DeployedResources
                |
                |__webapps
                |__WEB-INF
                      |
                      |___ApplicationContext.xml
                      |
                      |___web.xml
```

I am running an project with Spring 2.5 version, Hibernate, JSF, and I am doing a Login by using Spring-Security I am getting a Mapping Issues.

**Exception is:**

```
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:dynaprice' did not find a matching property.
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Sep 14 2016 12:12:26 UTC
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.72.0
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\sp\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\sp\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.72
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:52817
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\sp\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\sp\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.72
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\sp\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\sp\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.72\endorsed
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Users\sp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3030 ms
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:45 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [361] milliseconds.
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\sp\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\dynaprice\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\sp\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\dynaprice\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\sp\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\dynaprice\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\sp\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\dynaprice\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://mojarra.dev.java.net/mojarra_ext is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: 
        http://java.sun.com/jsf/html
     is already defined
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@22c4d80a: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Nov 24 22:59:55 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/beans/DataSource.xml]
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml]
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/com/dynaprice/customer/spring/CustomerBean.xml]
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:56 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    ... 31 more

Nov 24, 2016 10:59:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    ... 31 more

Nov 24, 2016 10:59:56 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.0 (SNAPSHOT 20100817) for context '/dynaprice'
Nov 24, 2016 10:59:59 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:00 PM com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager addBean
WARNING: JSF1074: Managed bean named 'pieChartBean' has already been registered.  Replacing existing managed bean class type com.dynaprice.PieChartBean with com.dynaprice.PieChartBean.
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/dynaprice/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/dynaprice] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 24, 2016 11:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 19165 ms
```

**Spring-Security.xml**

```
    <b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">




    <b:bean  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <b:property name="location">
     <b:value>classes/config/spring/beans/DataSource.xml</b:value>
   </b:property>
</b:bean>



    <http auto-config="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/webapp/*" access="UserName"/>
    <form-login login-page="/Login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/Login.xhtml"/>
    </http>


`<authentication-manager> 
<authentication-provider>
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
</authentication-provider> 
</authentication-manager>
</b:beans>
`
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">






<!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="classes/config/spring/beans/DataSource.xml"/>

<import resource="classes/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>

    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="classes/com/dynaprice/customer/spring/CustomerBean.xml"/>

    <import resource="classpath:/resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml"/> 

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
  classpath:/resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml 
   </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
```

org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener

```
</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Home.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>



<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Your imports are all wrong... The `Spring-Security.xml` and `HibernateSessionFactory.xml` reside in the root of your classpath (according to what ou posted here.). So both should be `classpath:/your-xml-here.xml`. And I suspect that goes for all your files. Basically all or your imports are wrong. The same applies to the location in your `contextConfigLocation` you are already importing it so just remove the additional loading of the security xml.

Comment: Hello, thank you for commenting on my issue,Except Spring-Security.xml all the configurations are mapping correctly if i remove Spring-Security.xml it is working fine and it is showing Output too. why for this Spring-Security.xml it is raising exception.. feeling Sad trying since 2 days with same exceptions.  schemas for all  xml files are fine can you please tell na..

Comment: The files aren't where you state they are. The other ones probably don't even load either it fails on the first one. If the files are in the location you state they are they simply won't load, if they load then the files aren't in the location you stated they were.

Comment: Bro, the versions of Spring Security Libraries are different in that case also  can this exception occours..?? like i have Spring Security 3.1,spring security core 2.6,and spring security web 3.0.1 v will it effect the se exceptions..??

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with the version. As stated all of your locations are simply wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spring-Security.xml` file resides in classpath (`src/main/resources` folder), so in your `ApplicationContext.xml`, you need to change from `<import resource="classpath:/resources/config/spring/beans/Spring-Security.xml"/>` 
to `<import resource="classpath:Spring-Security.xml"/>`

Similarly, you need to change the other files which are available in `src/main/resources`

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but i am getting same Exception.As i am a beginner can you please tell me  EXCEPTION IS                                                      org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/Spring-Security.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring-Security.xml];